# Include orientation change for resize events

Tags: javascript, jquery, orientation, window-resize

For a slider I use some neat jQuery magic to have an overlaying text scale with the height of the slider, so it never overlaps the slider itself. While this is working pretty good I am having trouble make jQuery recognize an orientation change on mobile devices as well as from changing from window to full screen and vice versa on desktop browsers. Is there a way to make the following listen to those changes as well?

```
fontresize = function () {
    var fontSize = jQuery("#slider").height() * 0.34; 
    jQuery("#slider_caption").css('font-size', fontSize);
};
jQuery(window).resize(fontresize);
jQuery(window).load(fontresize);
```

**Edit:** I am using jQuery, not jQuery mobile. Would it be recommended, for only this small problem, to include jQuery mobile as well?

Answer (score 1):

Theres the "orientationchange" event

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
  alert("The orientation has changed!");
});
```

I believe that ["on"](https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/) is the best practice to handle events, in your case it would be:

```
$(window).on("orientationchange resize load", fontresize);
```

Edit: and here are som fullscreen change events:

```
$(document).on('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange MSFullscreenChange', fontresize);
```

Edit: Since you are using a very outdated jQuery, maybe a JS event-binding works:

```
 window.addEventListener('orientationchange', fontresize);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch so far. But isn’t orientationchange only available through jQuery mobile? This may be why, though it throws no error, nothing happens on orientationchange, i.e. it doesn’t seem to be working :(.

Comment: its availilble in the mozilla documentation and in the safari documentation so im guessing its a "general" event and not something specific to jQuery mobile
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange
 and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Comment: This triggers on my iphone in safari running jquery 2.1.1

Comment: Unfortunately in my example it doesn’t trigger the update and stays on the wrong size, i.e. no resize, both on Firefox and Chrome for Android. I would assume it may be connected to using WordPress with its shipped jQuery 1.11?

Comment: **Edit**: Just saw your addition for fullscreen changes. They don’t seem to work on Desktop either.

Comment: You can bypass the jquery binding and do it just JS like this:
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', fontresize);

Regarding the fullscreenevents, FF and Chrome trigger a resize event on fullscreen mode (since it actually resizes when going fullscreen)

Comment: Unfortunately, still it does not do anything. You can try out the live example: http://www.testboks.com/kitenlernen . The jQuery/JS in the script.js. Any ideas?

Comment: i dont have the devices you are reffering to not working, so i cant test, it works on my iphone and on desktop. Its not related, but line 32 should be fontresize(); with a parenthesis since youre actually calling it, and not passing a reference to it. And also your function variable should have a "var" in front of it, or you can try to declare your function like so on line 27: function fontresize() {

Comment: Hey there, fixed the two things you mentioned. Just to confirm: When manually resizing the browser window, the script successfully also resizes the font-size, that is the case in my testings. Once I do abrupt changes, i.e. change orientation on Android devices or change from window to fullscreen on a Desktop browser, the script does not realise a change and sticks to the former font size. Is that different for you?

Comment: i cannot answer for an android device as i dont own one. Desktop Chrome and FF trigger the resize event on fullscreen changes

Comment: Are you using a Windows machine as regards to Desktop? No matter what browser I try, the site does not react to changes to/from fullscreen/maximised window to/from window. The text size on the slider still remains the same and does not adapt. It only changes when I manually narrow down or widen the window. What could I possibly be doing wrong here:(?

Comment: I set up this jsFiddle so you can try the events (with jQuery 1.11). For example my firefox going fullscreen on win8 triggers three resize events. That way you can determine if its the actual events that dont get triggered or maybe some other bloat that goes wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/hmpnte0t/